# I would love to ask for clarification on a question but it appears that comments have been blocked because of some drama

Tags: support

related OP:

[As a professional photographer, how can one handle a wedding photographer being rude or demanding in a way that will compromise overall image quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/67489/as-a-professional-photographer-how-can-one-handle-a-wedding-photographer-being)

I'm confused by the OP is talking about his sister in law, and after that about the second shooter and then talking multiple times about "her". It feels to me like he some times is referring to his sister in law by "she" and sometimes by the 2nd shooter.

I would love to have placed a comment on this requesting the OP for clarification. But it appears like there was some drama before that went to make clarifications on this not welcome.

What I'm asking here for is:

What can I do in this kind of situation to get clarification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All she's refer to the primary photographer with whom the discussion occured.  If you have questions that either don't fit in comments or if comments are disabled, then you can hop in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) and ask there if anyone has an idea.  In some cases it won't be particularly visible to the OP, but someone else might have a better understanding and it will let the moderator know what your confusion is.  (In this case I (the OP) regularly checks chat myself.)

Comment: I also think meta is a perfectly acceptable place to ask this type of a question especially since the question is locked in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Comments asking for question clarity are okay and would normally only get deleted when the reason for them was resolved or it was clear that the target of the comment wasn't going to do anything.

The reason for the lock, and my rather blunt statement, was that almost every answer was followed up with a lengthy comment debate about it and, in some cases, less than polite behaviour and this was after I had already asked to keep that sort of discussion in chat.